# Entity Framework: Execute multiple commands in one round trip

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, command, roundtrip

***Situation***

I have many parameterized SQL commands. I execute these commands one after the other in a loop and looks like this:

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
    using (var ts = _Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            _Context.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var cmd in _Commands)
            {
                if (cmd.Parameter != null)
                {
                    _Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd.Sql, cmd.Parameter.ToArray()); 
                }
            }

            ts.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ts.Rollback();
            throw new Exception("SaveChanges");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works, also transcaction rollback works as expected.

My command class looks like this:

```
public class SqlBuilderCommand
{
    public string Sql { get; set; }

    public List<SqlParameter>  Parameter {get;set;}
}
```

***Possible duplicates without concrete solution***

I have figured out several, possible duplicates to this question. The closest one is this:

[Possible Duplicate 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975679/how-to-send-multiple-commands-to-sql-server-2008-with-one-round-trip)

Unfortunately, it doesn't help me with the Entity Framework (or I just don't get it)

***Questions***

1. Is it possible to execute all the commands in the list in one round trip?
2. If not, is it possible with ADO.NET?

***SOLUTION AND DRAWBACKS / LIMITATIONS***

Thanks to @Evgeni for the right answer.Yes, you can concatenate many SQL-Strings and just send the parameter as a list in one round trip. That's great.

But there is a limitation with SQL-Server. SQL-Server only accepts a maximum of 2100 parameters with one command. So if you have an object with 7 database columns, the maximum bulk insert is 300 objects per command. Otherwise you get an exception.

If I do that for 5000 objects, it leads to 17 bulk inserts (5000/300). I stopped the time for 5000 objects and it is still 8-9 seconds, which is way too slow, because I know, that raw SQL will do it much, much faster.

*At this point, I think there is no way around raw SQL for me, unless someone could tell me, that there is a way to speed up sql commands.*

Maybe I will write a follow up question to this. Damn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically you can execute multiple commands in one go:

```
    var n1 = new SqlParameter("@name1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    n1.Value = "name 1 ";
    var u1 = new SqlParameter("@uid1", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    u1.Value = Guid.Parse("guid here");
    var n2 = new SqlParameter("@name2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    n2.Value = "name2";
    var u2 = new SqlParameter("@uid2", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    u2.Value = Guid.Parse("guid here");
    var sqlParams = new[]
    {
        n1, n2, u1, u2
    };

    using (var db = new DbContext("default"))
    {

        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
            Update property set name = @name1 where uid = @uid1; 
            Update property set name = @name2 where uid = @uid2;", sqlParams);
    }
```

So I'd imagine if you concatenate your sql, it should just work.

Comment: You can totally replace strings with sql parameters. I'll update code...

Comment: Aaaaahhh, NOW I get, what you tried to explain to me. I will evaluate this solution at the end of the week, because I have no time today and tomorrow. It looks very promising from here. If it fits, I will mark your answer as valid and post my solution in the question. Thank you Evgeni!

Comment: This is the right answer. The only problem I have right now, that the maximum number of paramters for SQL-Server is 2100 per command. So if you have an object with 7 database columns, you could send max 300 with one command. For 5000 inserts, I stopped a time of 8 seconds which is still to slow in my opinion. I think there is no way around raw SQL. I had a look in3rd party libraries, which can handle bulk inserts for EF and they also produce raw SQL. Anyway - your answer was absoluteley correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also wrote the solution and limitation in the question.